# HIVE script - Specify file name as S3 Location

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

I am exporting data from DynamoDB to S3 using follwing script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TableDynamoDB(col1 String, col2 String)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES (
"dynamodb.table.name" = "TableDynamoDB",
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "col1:col1,col2:col2"
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TableS3(col1 String, col2 String)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION 's3://myBucket/DataFiles/MyData.txt';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE TableS3
SELECT * FROM TableDynamoDB;
```

In S3, I want to write the output to a given file name (MyData.txt)
but the way it is working currently is that above script created folder with name 'MyData.txt'
and then generated a file with some random name under this folder.

Is it at all possible to specify a file name in S3 using HIVE?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- There are 2 different ways hadoop can write data to s3. This [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) describes the differences in a little more detail. Since you are using the "s3" scheme, you are probably seeing a block number.
- In general, M/R jobs (and hive queries) are going to want to write their output to multiple files. This is an artifact of parallel processing. In practice, most commands/APIs in hadoop handle directories pretty seamlessly so you shouldn't let it bug you too much. Also, you can use things like `hadoop fs -getmerge` on a directory to read all of the files in a single stream.
- AFAIK, the LOCATION argument in the DDL for an external hive table is always treated as a directory for the reasons above.